# Statistical Test on R for categorical variable across time

Tags: r, categorical-data, repeated-measures

I'm currently working on a paper based on data we got from a questionnaire. I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to go about it when it comes to the best test.
This questionnaire looks at the same sample of people across multiple time points, a year before, one month after, and six months after a therapeutic intervention.
The result of that intervention is measured with a categorical variable, dividing the sample across four groups (with Cat 1 < Cat 2 < Cat 3 < Cat 4).
The final table looks like this :

[image: 1]

The numbers here are for example.

I'm trying to determine if the intervention causes a statistically significant change, mainly if that intervention makes people go from cat 4 to cat 1, or at least decreases their category rank.
Obviously I can't use an ANOVA (categorical variable), so i was thinking pairwise MacNemar but it can only be used with a table of 2x2. Am I supposed to use a pairwise MacNemar test for every category and comparing it with the rest of the sample ?
I would very much appreciate any amount of guidance.
Thank you in advance.

MacNemar requires a 2x2 table which isn't the case here.
Chi2 wouldn't work because it's a paired test I need, considering we measure the same group of people across time.

Comment: So you ran your experiment without first thinking about how you would analyse the results?  That's very, very poor practice, IMHO.  Your questions indicate   that you clearly need advice from an experienced statistician.  That's best found on StackExchange, not here.

Comment: Do you have the data for each person (i.e., for each person the category before and after), or is your raw data the table you posted? If the former, you could consider some form of [ordinal regression](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/), e.g. `polr(cat ~ time + person_id)` with `time` either a continuous variable or a factor with three levels (maybe better as factor?).